# SPARQL Query resource filter by another resource's data

Tags: filtering, sparql

studying for an exam I have in Advanced modelling and have a question in regards to a SPARQL approach to a problem. This is an exam question from last year's exam :

QUESTION : Write a SPARQL query that lists all nearby hotels in Paris with latitude and longitude that are within 0.006
degrees latitude and 0.01 degrees longitude of the hotel named “Hotel Saint-Germain-des-Pres”.

- Assume you have an RDF graph that uses the dc:title predicate for all resource titles. Some of the
  resources represent hotels. They have the rdf:type schema:Hotel .
- The RDF graph also uses the schema:address predicate to describe the address of each hotel. An
  address resource has rdf:type schema:PostalAddress . We will pretend each postal address has a
  schema:city predicate that gives the hotel's city as a string literal.
- Each hotel in the graph also has Geo coordinates for latitude and longitude.

So far I have come up with :

```
SELECT ?hotelName WHERE {
?hotel rdf:type schema:Hotel;
    dc:title "Hotel Saint-Germain-des-Pres"^^xsd:string
    geo:latitude ?targLat;
    geo:longitude ?targLong .
?hotel rdf:type schema:Hotel;
    schema:city "Paris"^^xsd:string;
    dc:title ?hotelName;
    geo:latitude ?lat
    geo:longtitude ?long .
    FILTER((geo:long <= targLong + 0.006 && geo:long >= targLong - 0.006) && (geo:lat <= targLat + 0.01 && geo:lat >= targLat - 0.01))

}

Pseudo: ?hotelName long & lat within long(0.006)/lat(0.01) of"Hotel Saint-Germain-des-Pres"
```

But hit a wall when it comes to relating that the latitude & longitude must be within another resource's location.

How is it possible to show this restriction in SPARQL?

Thanks for any answers in advance.

Comment: You first have to bind the information of latitude and longitude to variables, as you did also for the title. Then you can apply the FILTER on these variables to model the restriction. The difference must be below two given values, Think of a cartesian coordinate system. How would you compute the distance of two points there? (hint: SPARQL supports some functions on numeric values like `abs(arg)`-> absolute value of `arg`.

Comment: Have you considered using `<http://jena.apache.org/spatial#nearby`? You can find a few very simple examples [here](http://nomisma.org/documentation/sparql)

Comment: Are you asking for `?x geo:latitude ?xlat . :hotel geo:latitude ?hlat . filter (?hlat - 0.006 <= ?xlat && ?xlat <= ?hlat + 0.006)`?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor is it not just `FILTER(abs(?xlat - ?hlat) <= 0.006)`?

Comment: @aksw that's even better :)